# How to add Excel ranges and text to email body, in specific positions?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from multiple ranges in an Excel sheet to an email body.

Below is the code I have come up with.

How to make ranges paste one under the other and how to add text after ranges but before signature from Outlook.

How it is now:

[image]

```
Sub reportCostLunch()

Dim recipient(0) As Variant
recipient(0) = ""
Dim outlook As Object
Dim email As Object
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sheet, sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim SDest As String, title As String, slot As String

Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1")
Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET2")
title = sheet.Range("D13").Value
Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set email = outlook.CreateItem(0)

With email
    SDest = ""
    For i = LBound(recipient) To UBound(recipient)
        If SDest = "" Then
            SDest = recipient(i)
        Else
            SDest = SDest & ";" & recipient(i)
        End If
    Next i
    
    .To = SDest
    .Subject = title
    .Display

    Set xInspect = email.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

    Worksheets("SHEET2").Range("C44:AF71").Copy

    pageEditor.Application.Selection.start = 1
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdChartPicture)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.InsertParagraphAfter

    Worksheets("SHEET2").Range("C26:AF44").Copy

    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdChartPicture)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.InsertParagraphAfter           
    .Display
    email.HTMLBody = "SOME TEXT " _
     & email.HTMLBody & " some text"
              
    Set pageEditor = Nothing
    Set xInspect = Nothing
End With

Set email = Nothing
Set outlook = Nothing
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm is one option.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Email Body in VBA.

Put it together into one variable, including all your paragraphs and line breaks. Then use that one variable for

`email.HTMLBody = varEmailBody`

**Edit:** If you use `.HTMLBody` you can't copy/paste anything. You need to construct the HTML as text somewhere (in your code). Ron de Bruin has excellent examples of all kinds of Excel to Outlook email scenarios. Here is one for mailing an Excel range in an HTML body: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm -- You may need to construct one contiguous range in your worksheet (maybe on a hidden sheet) that you can process in the VBA as one range.

Comment: but how add copy ranges to variable and past them?

Comment: ok, I got it but: 1. it didn't copy conditional formatting, 2. didn't add my signature. Any idea how to change it?

Comment: Maybe you need to take a look at the docmentation and see what's possible and adjust your expectations. 1. by definition, conditional formatting requires the cells to be evaluated (by Excel) and the formatting is dynamically applied. If the cells are taken out of the Excel application, how is Excel supposed to reach into Outlook and format them? -- and 2. The signature is not part of the body. There is a command to use the default or even a specific signature, but I don't know it off the top of my head. I would have to look it up in the documentation. So, I expect you could do that, too.

Comment: @vipmaciej If you make the cell ranges with HTML you could colour the background of the cells to match the sheet. Otherwise, if a screenshot is ok, maybe you could grab the DC of the Excel window and add attach it as a an inline picture?